# How can I install many packages with pip from requirements

Tags: python, django, pip

If I install packages like this:

`pip install selenium`

then I can see the packages with `yolk -l`

If I install the packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt`, after all the messages and cloning the packages are not installed, do not appear in `yolk -l`

Where did the packages go?

The output is very huge:

```
hon.org/simple/django-redis/), version: 1.3
    Found link http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-redis/django-redis-2.0c3.tar.gz#md5=ff8d49ef793fb6319d72f9d228999bee (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-redis/), version: 2.0c3
    Found link http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-redis/django-redis-2.2.2.tar.gz#md5=3c013c79ec63c439d5b46fb3b2f86ebe (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-redis/), version: 2.2.2
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-redis/); not a file
  Analyzing links from page https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/apple-touch-icon-114.png (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); unknown archive format: .png
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/apple-touch-icon-144.png (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); unknown archive format: .png
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/tree/4807b5d3370e227d0e44aa955ea4779b72545eb0 (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/commits/master.atom (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); unknown archive format: .atom
    Skipping link https://github.com/login?return_to=%2Fniwibe%2Fdjango-redis (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/stargazers (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/network (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/pulls (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/issues (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/graphs (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis#readme (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Could not parse version from link: https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/archive/master.zip (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis)
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/archive/master.zip (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); wrong project name (not django-redis)
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis.git (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); unknown archive format: .git
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/git@github.com:niwibe/django-redis.git (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); unknown archive format: .git
    Skipping link git://github.com/niwibe/django-redis.git (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); unknown archive format: .git
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/tags (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/downloads (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/tree/devel (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/tree/feature/master-slave (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/tree/feature/redis-client (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/tree/feature/simple-autofailover (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
    Skipping link https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis/tree/master (from https://github.com/niwibe/django-redis); not a file
```

---

```
python.org/simple/django-nose/), version 0.0.2 doesn't match ==1.1
  Ignoring link http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-nose/django-nose-1.0.tar.gz#md5=9f27926c42c58ea93973db236f22cd72 (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-nose/), version 1.0 doesn't match ==1.1
  Ignoring link http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-nose/django-nose-0.0.1.tar.gz#md5=461c6f49ca91d17a18939874653ae42c (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-nose/), version 0.0.1 doesn't match ==1.1
  Ignoring link http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-nose/django-nose-0.0.3.tar.gz#md5=ba2a5565752468d2016e5d61f93997d8 (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-nose/), version 0.0.3 doesn't match ==1.1
  Ignoring link http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-nose/django-nose-0.1.tar.gz#md5=174e5a7f00bf159b0592dd7a2e98fc71 (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-nose/), version 0.1 doesn't match ==1.1
  Ignoring link http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-nose/django-nose-0.1.2.tar.gz#md5=a8c7ad89adb0c7cddb974241ae746d8a (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-nose/), version 0.1.2 doesn't match ==1.1
  Ignoring link http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-nose/django-nose-0.1.3.tar.gz#md5=5b4f54f7e0e251b169d86ad6ee6b9b10 (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-nose/), version 0.1.3 doesn't match ==1.1
  Downloading django-nose-1.1.tar.gz

  Downloading from URL http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-nose/django-nose-1.1.tar.gz#md5=606ab8a582f1d2037b048b7c4e246e85 (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-nose/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-nose

    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/django_nose.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/django_nose.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/django_nose.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/django_nose.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/django_nose.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_nose.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_nose.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory 'django_nose'

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory 'testapp'

    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_nose.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip-build/django-nose has version 1.1, which satisfies requirement django-nose==1.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
Downloading/unpacking Pillow==1.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))

  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/Pillow
  URLs to search for versions for Pillow==1.7.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)):
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/Pillow/1.7.7
```

---

```
http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-extra-views/), version 0.5.1 doesn't match ==0.2.5
  Downloading django-extra-views-0.2.5.tar.gz

  Downloading from URL http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-extra-views/django-extra-views-0.2.5.tar.gz#md5=a8308e656871279ff6461f1aba45ecf1 (from http://pypi.python.org/simple/django-extra-views/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django-extra-views

    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/django_extra_views.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/django_extra_views.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/django_extra_views.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/django_extra_views.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/django_extra_views.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_extra_views.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_extra_views.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/django_extra_views.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip-build/django-extra-views has version 0.2.5, which satisfies requirement django-extra-views==0.2.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
Downloading/unpacking pyPdf==1.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))

  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyPdf
  URLs to search for versions for pyPdf==1.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)):
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyPdf/1.13
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyPdf/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyPdf/1.13
  Getting page http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyPdf/1.13: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (pyPdf/1.13)
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyPdf/1.13 when looking for download links for pyPdf==1.13 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

Comment: Are there any errors while running `pip install -r requirements.txt`?

Comment: Paste output of `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the packages with `pip install -r requirements.txt` and run `pip freeze` first. The packages should appear on there.  If not, they didn't install correctly.  If they appear in the freeze output, then running `yolk -l` should net the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that few of packages have error in them during installing in your `requirements.txt` file. If one of them fails even then nothing will be installed.

It has happened with me as well. Just remove that package from the file and everything will be ok